# Use the command window to display a statement about a comment

Tags: java

Help me understand what is being asked here. The question instructs me to use the command window to display the following statement about comments:

"Program comments are nonexecuting statements you add to a file for the purpose of documentation."

Also include the same statement in three different comments in the class; each comment should use  one of the three different methods of including comments  in a Java class.

What is the "command window"? Is it the window that appears when I press run? If so wouldn't comments not display at all.

Comment: "the three different methods of including comments in a Java class" ? I know only of two... BTW the word "Also" implies that there's a part of the question you didn't post - am I right?

Comment: @alfasin-OP is talking about documentation comment in Java which publishees author,etc! `/** documentation */`

Comment: It is just asking you to print that statement on the console and have that same statement be comments in the program as s single line, multi line and documentation comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, depending on your IDE, the command window is the prompt which you can start (or stop the program with), receive output and enter input into the program. If you are using the Windows CMD software, you generally will use `javac [filename].java` to compile and `java [filename]` to run the code.

Inside your Java code, each line is run as a meaningful statement causing the program to do something. However comments are used to ignore lines in your program, such as messages for yourself or documentation to note to others who may view the program, how to use it.

Examples of comments are (single line): `\\ This line will NOT be run`
and (block):

```
/*
Lots of text can go here
This will not be run at all.
Not even the third line.
*/
```

However you are asked to display a line and that can be done with the *print (or println)* command from the *out* subclass of *System* class.
This would look like:

`System.out.print("Program comments are nonexecuting statements you add to a file for the purpose of documentation.");`

And that way the string of text,

> Program comments are nonexecuting statements you add to a file for the purpose of documentation.

is printed into the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Windows Command Prompt Window is what is meant there.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window